# issues reading from plist file

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a simple plist file with some user preferences for a card game I'm writing.
I have also created a controller that reads and writes to this plist file which is a singelton.
everything works fine, but then after a couple of tries it stops working. 
Logging the values to the console it shows the list returning a value of 0 which causes my app to crash
I have deleted the plist and created a new one and then the same story, works fine for 2 or three time and then boom zero.

here is a copy of the controller singelton code:

```
@implementation userOptionsController

static userOptionsController* _sharedOptionsController = nil;
@synthesize backgroundSound=_backgroundSound;
@synthesize soundEffects = _soundEffects;
@synthesize coach = _coach;
@synthesize numberOfDecks = _numberOfDecks ;

+(userOptionsController*)sharedOptionsController{

@synchronized([userOptionsController class])
{
    if(!_sharedOptionsController)

        [[self alloc]init];
    return _sharedOptionsController;
}
return nil;
}

+(id)alloc
{
@synchronized ([userOptionsController class])
{
    NSAssert(_sharedOptionsController == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of      userOptionsController singleton");
    _sharedOptionsController = [super alloc];
    return _sharedOptionsController;
}
return nil;
}


- (id) init {

self = [super init];
if (self) {

    }
return self;
 }

-(void)readPlistFile
{
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"playerPrefOptions.plist"]; 

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) 
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"playerPrefOptions" ofType:@"plist"];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; 
}
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
self.backgroundSound = [[temp objectForKey:@"backgroundSounds"]boolValue];
self.soundEffects = [[temp objectForKey:@"soundEffects"]boolValue];
self.coach =[[temp objectForKey:@"coach"]boolValue];
self.numberOfDecks = [[temp objectForKey:@"numberOfDecks"]intValue];
}

-(void)writeOptionsToFile
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"playerPrefOptions.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

NSNumber *moshe = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.numberOfDecks];

[infoDict setObject: moshe forKey:@"numberOfDecks"];
[infoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.coach] forKey:@"coach"];
[infoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.backgroundSound]   forKey:@"backgroundSounds"];
[infoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.soundEffects] forKey:@"soundEffects"];
[infoDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

}

@end
```

so the property :

```
int numberOfDecks =[userOptionsController sharedOptionsController].numberOfDecks;
```

will return zero.

any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: Try by removing the `.plist` from here `stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"playerPrefOptions.plist"]`

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't write zero to the plist file? Some logging may help.

Comment: I think you should look at  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html and in particular the Core foundation part in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-97383  which I found easier and more reliable to use.

Comment: Also here is the Docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html. I use this for my OSX apps which include system preference panes which I do not want the prefs stored in any shared plist of system events. I think they should all be ok with iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use a plist for this content, it looks like `NSUserDefaults` is a more appropriate location.

Instead of shipping the app with a default plist file, instead just `registerDefaults:` with `NSUserDefaults` (often done in your app delegate `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`).

Then, whenever any changes are made just update `NSUserDefaults` and call `synchronize` to save the changes.

Comment: Thanks Wain, I'm kind of new to this and I read that plists are a quick and easy way to store information, especially like in my case where I only need to store 3 variables. I hear that NSUserDefaults is more complicated but I'll have to go with that since for the life of me I cant make that plist thing work. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see what it does (what logs are output):

```
@implementation userOptionsController

+ (userOptionsController*)sharedOptionsController
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedObject;
}

- (id) init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}

-(void)readPlistFile
{
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"playerPrefOptions.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"playerPrefOptions" ofType:@"plist"];

        if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR - file couldn't be copied: %@", error);
        }
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

    if (temp == nil) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR - file couldn't be read");
    }

    self.backgroundSound = [[temp objectForKey:@"backgroundSounds"]boolValue];
    self.soundEffects = [[temp objectForKey:@"soundEffects"]boolValue];
    self.coach =[[temp objectForKey:@"coach"]boolValue];
    self.numberOfDecks = [[temp objectForKey:@"numberOfDecks"]intValue];
}

-(void)writeOptionsToFile
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"playerPrefOptions.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

    NSNumber *moshe = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.numberOfDecks];

    [infoDict setObject: moshe forKey:@"numberOfDecks"];
    [infoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.coach] forKey:@"coach"];
    [infoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.backgroundSound]   forKey:@"backgroundSounds"];
    [infoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.soundEffects] forKey:@"soundEffects"];

    if (![infoDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR - failed to write the new file (%@)", path);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Completed write of:\n%@", infoDict);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: it logs a value if before moving to the game play itself I go to my options menu and reset my choices, otherwise there is no log at all, which means to me that the file is not being written at all or maybe somewhere it writes zero to the file

Comment: The above will log errors on read and either an error or confirmation on write.

Comment: there is no write performed, unless if I go and make changes in the options menu. I do have a call to the writePlistFile on the appDelagate, applicationWillTerminate but for some reason it does not perform the action.

Comment: The chances of `applicationWillTerminate` are pretty small. Usually the app will go into the background before being terminated, then it won't be called. Often the app won't be terminated, it'll just go to the background and then return to the foreground...